# Linux make specify lib location

Tags: linux, makefile, dependencies, posix

I'm trying to build hostapd after removing it ( I can't use yaourt for this as my network adapters aren't working any more ). When I try to use make for this purpose, here's the output :

```
netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory
```

I therefore installed libnl 3.2.25 after downloading it with another pc, but running make with hostapd still throws the same error. I think it's because of this ( appears when configuring libnl ) :

```
 NOTE

There have been some changes starting with 3.2 regarding where and how libnl
is being installed on the system in order to allow multiple libnl versions
to be installed in parallel:

- Headers will be installed in ${prefix}/include/libnl3, therefore
  you will need to add "-I/usr/include/libnl3" to CFLAGS

- The library basename was renamed to libnl-3, i.e. the SO names become
  libnl-3.so., libnl-route-3.so, etc.

- libtool versioning was assumed, to ease detection of compatible library
  versions.
```

The problem being : I don't know how to tell make where libnl is, and as there's no configure file, where should I add the "-I/usr/include/libnl3" ? Sorry if that's a dumb question but I read make's doc without finding an answer, and I've never ran into this issue before.

Comment: check /usr/local/include - if you cant find it here, run a find command in /usr/ or / to look for genl.h

Comment: I solved it by installing an older version of libnl. Thanks though !